# CSS Animation on Menu item is not working when hovering

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I wanted to add a `hover` effect to my menu item, so when hovered, an line would be transitioning under it, and the line would expand from the middle out. I have included links two 2 gifs (one showing the intended animation and one showing the current result.

The structure is as follows

```css
#main-nav .navbar-nav li:hover .top_level::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  width: calc(100%);
}

#main-nav .navbar-nav li:hover .top_level::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #000;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, transform 0.3s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease 0s !important;
    width: calc(100%);
    }
.navbar-nav li .top_level {
    font-family: "Brandon Bold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px !important;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 25px 0px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-color .25s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#main-nav {
    text-align: left;
}

ul#main-nav {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
ul#main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-nav li {
    padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="top_level" href="/">Cuffs</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

The current result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i2Hp.jpg

The intended result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTUs6.jpg

How can it be, that the animation doesn't load?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Hello, please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As above, please create a codepen or something we can run

Comment: you don't create an initial states - both your initial (what looks to be your initial state) and hover states are on your hover and your final transition looks invalid (you wouldn't need the vendor prefix on the non prefixed version) and it would override your valid transition before it

Comment: I have added a snippet instead, but it doesn't work in that tool. The code above works as seen in current state gif when onsite. I can't get it to work in the snippet editor. @Pete Could you please elaborate what i'm missing+ Thank you very much for your help though, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is only the second selector (the initial status), which should be `#main-nav .navbar-nav li .top_level::after`  instead of `#main-nav .navbar-nav li:hover .top_level::after`

Remove the `:hover` in there and it will work, as it does in the snippet below.

```css
#main-nav .navbar-nav li:hover .top_level::after {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
transform: scaleX(1);
width: calc(100%);
}

#main-nav .navbar-nav li .top_level::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #000;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, transform 0.3s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease 0s !important;
    width: calc(100%);
    }
.navbar-nav li .top_level {
    font-family: "Brandon Bold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px !important;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 25px 0px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-color .25s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#main-nav {
    text-align: left;
}

ul#main-nav {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
ul#main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-nav li {
    padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="top_level" href="/">Cuffs</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```